# How to do grouped full imports in Scala?

Tags: scala, import

So these are all valid way to import in Scala.

```
scala> import scala.util.matching.Regex
import scala.util.matching.Regex

scala> import scala.util.matching._
import scala.util.matching._

scala> import scala.util.matching.{Regex, UnanchoredRegex}
import scala.util.matching.{Regex, UnanchoredRegex}
```

But how to do a valid grouped full import?

```
scala> import scala.util.{control._, matching._}
<console>:1: error: '}' expected but '.' found.
import scala.util.{control._, matching._}
                          ^
```

Comment: Just use two lines. Sometimes brevity can be overdone.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Why do you say that?

Comment: Because I think trying to save a line here is just unnecessary.

Comment: The one I mentioned was just an example. My actual code is ending up having a lot of imports from the same package.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use import sub-expression as an import selector. According to specification on [Import Clauses](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#import-clauses)

> The most general form of an import expression is a list of import selectors
>   { x1 => y1,…,xn => yn, _ }

Regarding your question, the closest one-liner is:

```
scala> import scala.util._, control._, matching._
import scala.util._
import control._
import matching._
```